# Function that formats functions

Tags: r

When you package R code, it loses some formatting that is otherwise unnecessary. I feel like this was a function, somewhere, maybe in the `utils` package. But I can't seem to find it nor do I have the appropriate vocabulary to goolge it.

Does anyone recall what the name of the function is? Or what package it's in?

Or perhaps, know of a function that otherwise strips formatting (like carriage returns/new lines) from a function or code block?

Comment: `removeSource`?  `deparse`?

Comment: That's it I think! `deparse`! Yes, that was exactly what I wanted. Please add as an answer.